# Select the first occurrence of records with today's date using time field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a `date` field and a `time(7)` field for each record. Once the record is inserted into the database it will have the insertion day's date and the time inserted logged.

Now I would like to select all the records from `Table1 INNER JOIN Table2` that are of **today's date with the first occurrence**, because the records can be duplicate. I have tried using the `time(7)` field to select the least time of today's date where `record1 = 'ABC'`, but that does not return any results and I am sure the query should return 1 result since it is logged twice with different times but with today's date. How can I select the first ever occurrence of a product with today's date?

**Example:**

```
SELECT ProductName, Description, Quantity,
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Transactions
    ON Products.ProductID = Transactions.ProductID
WHERE Transactions.ProductID = 'A6612'
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), `Transactions.Date_Tracked, 103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 103)
    AND Time_Tracked = (
        SELECT min(Time_Tracked)
        FROM Transactions
        )
    AND Country = 'United States'
```

Comment: How many records must return the request?

Comment: One record since I have two entries of the product, one at `09:15:04` and the other is on `09:15:41` so it will pick the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use option with EXISTS operator. Also, you can avoid not an efficient condition(or predicate) using the CAST function instead of CONVERT into VARCHAR data type

```
SELECT p.ProductName, p.Description, p.Quantity
FROM Products p INNER JOIN Transactions t ON p.ProductID = t.ProductID
WHERE t.ProductID = 'A6612' 
  AND CAST(t.Date_Tracked AS date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
  AND EXISTS (                      
              SELECT 1
              FROM Transactions t2
              WHERE t.ProductID = t2.ProductID
                AND CAST(t2.Date_Tracked AS date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
              HAVING MIN(t2.Time_Tracked) = t.Time_Tracked                      
              ) 
  AND Country = 'United States'
```

If the request return one record, simply use an ORDER BY clause with the TOP clause.

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.ProductName, p.Description, p.Quantity
FROM Products p INNER JOIN Transactions t ON p.ProductID = t.ProductID
WHERE t.ProductID = 'A6612' 
  AND CAST(t.Date_Tracked AS date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
  AND p.Country = 'United States'
ORDER BY t.Time_Tracked
```

And finally if Date_Tracked has type datetime, then:

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.ProductName, p.Description, p.Quantity
FROM Products p INNER JOIN Transactions t ON p.ProductID = t.ProductID
WHERE t.ProductID = 'A6612' 
  AND CAST(t.Date_Tracked AS date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
  AND p.Country = 'United States'
ORDER BY CAST(t.Date_Tracked AS time)
```

Comment: Worked, just what I needed. Yes I have read about the ineffeciency of `Convert to varchar`good pointing it out.

Comment: No, you wrongly understood. There is nothing wrong with conversion. You missed a condition in the subquery. That's why your query returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you query should look like this,

```
SELECT ProductName, Description, Quantity,
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Transactions
    ON Products.ProductID = Transactions.ProductID
WHERE Transactions.ProductID = 'A6612'
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Transactions.Date_Tracked, 103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 103)
    AND Time_Tracked = (
        SELECT min(Time_Tracked)
        FROM Transactions
        WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Transactions.Date_Tracked, 103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 103)
        )
    AND Country = 'United States'
```

Comment: probably missing a bracket ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using rowid?

```
SELECT ProductName, Description, Quantity,
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Transactions
    ON Products.ProductID = Transactions.ProductID
WHERE Transactions.ProductID = 'A6612'
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), `Transactions.Date_Tracked, 103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 103)
    AND Transactions.rowid = (SELECT min(rowid)
        FROM Transactions group by productid,date) --This will give you the minimum rowid 
    AND Country = 'United States'                    --grouped by productid and date.
```